# how to update my hidden division data when form is submitted without reloading page

Tags: php, javascript

i want to know javascript code that is used for dynamic update on my site...
the problem is that,i have a hidden division which contain a form (like registration form )and 
i validate this form using php.
but when i submit the form ,the page is reloaded and division is hide according to property,i want to see what is happening with form submission,i have to click again on link to show division then i m able to see about any error if occur.
i m using xmlHTTP object to do this but my division is not remain visible during form validation due to page reloading.i don't have any idea that how do visible division until complete submission of form.

i need whole source code,because i have code but unable to modify it according to my need.

Comment: I don't see anyone writing a complete solution based on such a generic description. You should at least lay the basics of what you want (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make proper sense. But I hope you just want to know a way to submit the form without reloading the page.

You can achieve it by suing Ajax. Instead of using Submit Button, you should keep a normal button and implement the validation and other functions using Ajax. This will prevent you from reloading the page.